# django-tastypie making every database query twice

Tags: django, tastypie

This is my first post although I search the site all the time. I can't find evidence of anyone else having this problem.

I have a REST API built with django-tastypie using a MySQL database back-end. Every time the API is called (e.g. using a browser, or an angularJS front-end), the django-tastypie backend makes every database call twice.

Here is the output of the django SQL logger from one API call:

```
(0.019) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `products`; args=()
(0.020) SELECT `products`.`id` FROM `products` LIMIT 30; args=()
(0.023) SELECT (`product_styles`.`product_id`) AS `_prefetch_related_val`, `styles`.`id`, `styles`.`name` FROM `styles` INNER JOIN `product_styles` ON (`styles`.`id` = `product_styles`.`style_id`) WHERE `product_styles`.`product_id` IN (517, 518, 661, 662, 539, 429, 569, 571, 572, 573, 574, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 611, 597, 87, 88, 443, 509, 510, 511); args=(517, 518, 661, 662, 539, 429, 569, 571, 572, 573, 574, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 611, 597, 87, 88, 443, 509, 510, 511)
(0.020) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `products`; args=()
(0.020) SELECT `products`.`id` FROM `products` LIMIT 30; args=()
(0.022) SELECT (`product_styles`.`product_id`) AS `_prefetch_related_val`, `styles`.`id`, `styles`.`name` FROM `styles` INNER JOIN `product_styles` ON (`styles`.`id` = `product_styles`.`style_id`) WHERE `product_styles`.`product_id` IN (517, 518, 661, 662, 539, 429, 569, 571, 572, 573, 574, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 611, 597, 87, 88, 443, 509, 510, 511); args=(517, 518, 661, 662, 539, 429, 569, 571, 572, 573, 574, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 611, 597, 87, 88, 443, 509, 510, 511)
```

The timings are different but the queries are identical. I have confirmed by logging in MySQL that the duplicated queries are actually happening, it is not just a django logging problem. I've also confirmed using wireshark that only one http request and response is being sent, (i.e. it's not because I'm accidently making two API calls).

I have cut my models and resources code back to the bare bones required to reproduce the problem and included it below. Can anyone give some ideas on how to investigate this further? I'm stumped.

api.py

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource, Resource
from tastypie.fields import ToOneField, ToManyField
from FrameFish_aws.models import Product, ProductStyle, Style 

class StyleResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Style.objects.all()

class ProductResource(ModelResource):
    styles = ToManyField('FrameFish_aws.api.StyleResource', 'styles', full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Product.objects.all().prefetch_related('styles')
        resource_name = 'frames'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Style(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'styles'

class ProductStyle(models.Model):
    """Intermediate table for holding associating styles with products"""
    style = models.ForeignKey('Style', to_field='id')
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', to_field='id')
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'product_styles'

class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    styles = models.ManyToManyField('Style', through='ProductStyle')
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'products'
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), select_related 'is limited to single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one.'

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself. I was still running the django-debug-toolbar middlewar. I didn't realise that it worked by [re-executing every sql query](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/blob/master/debug_toolbar/views.py)... hence the duplicate queries.

Comment: I don't think it does re-execute the queries.  Are you sure about this?  PS you should accept your answer so this question does not show up in the unanswered list.